# Switch XFWM to Openbox on startup

Tags: xubuntu, openbox, xfwm4

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04 (core^ not whole desktop), and I prefer Openbox over the default XFWM. So, I installed `openbox` and added a `.desktop` launcher which executes `openbox --replace` to `.config/autostart` (ticked on `Session and Startup` settings).

The thing is, whenever I relog I do get the Openbox (whether I was on Openbox or on XFWM at the end of the last session), but I it's still xfwm whenever I reboot (and login to the same user).

Does anyone know what may be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

On your login screen, you're still set to log into XFWM.  At your login screen, you can change what you want to log into (XFWM or openbox) and it will remember the setting after reboots.

The method you're using now is a one-time switch into openbox, which is why when you reboot, you go right back into XFWM.

Different distros use different Display Managers (The login screen), and each one has an option somewhere on it to select which Window Manager you want to log into.  I'm not familiar with the latest Xubuntu, but what you're looking for is either a "Session" option, or a drop-down menu, or a little gear icon.  Those are the usual 3 types.